# how to create a custom url in both IOS and android app in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create a custom url.

Scenario is, user_1 can send some Id to user_2 through email.

The email must contain url. if user_2 taps the url, that must open my app if it is installed or else it should go to the App Store and also I need to save the Id that user_1 sent. How can I create the URL???

Answer (score 1):

`Deep linking` is a technique that allows an app to be opened to a specific UI or resource, in response to some external event.

By implementing a `deep linking` strategy, capable of navigation to an app from the
URLs.

Try to use the concept `Linking` provided in `React Native` Tutorials.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html

Or please follow [Deep Linking Your React Native App](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) explained by **Nader Dabit**.